# Multiple dependent SQL queries in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to build an app which requires that I make more than one query per view/controller.

Im trying to do the asynchronously using a nested structure, but the sql result comes up undefined in the inner closure.

This is the function Im using to do this:

```
var conn = db.config(mysql);

function run_queries(conn,callback) {

    conn.query(sql1, var1, function(err, res1) {

        if(err){ callback(err); return; }

        console.log(res1);     // RETURNS SUCCESSFULLY!

        conn.query(sql2, var2, function(err, res2) {

            if(err){ callback(err); return; }

            console.log(res2); // UNDEFINED :(

            callback(null, res2);

        });

    });

}

run_queries(conn,function(err, result){

    console.log(result);       // UNDEFINED :(

});
```

I have checked my SQL and it is without errors. If I swap sq1 with sq2, the outer closure returns the correct query for sq2.

The inner closure just isnt returning a query.

Comment: why did not use async module ?

Comment: Im new to node and not sure how to apply it in this case

Comment: http://caolan.github.io/async/  it's very important to understand async. I am going to use async.parallel and give you example for you.

Comment: much appreciated. I have used async to parse post data, but have not explored the module further. your response below was very helpful. thank you! just out of curiosity and for learning purposes, why do you think my code above was returning undefined in the inner closure?

Comment: asynchronous feature of nodeJs. can you try use setTimeout(function(){   
 \\ your conn.query code  },0).

Comment: but I thought using callbacks in such a nested structure accounted for node's asynchronous nature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async is a very useful for an asynchronous call. You can make your code well maintained using an async module.

Example of your code using `async.parallel`

```
var conn = db.config(mysql);
var async = require('async');

function run_queries(conn, cb) {


    async.parallel({

      res1: function (cb) {

        conn.query(sql1, var1, function (err, res1) {
          if (err) { cb(err) }
          else { cb(null, res1) }
        })
      },
      res2: function (cb) {

        conn.query(sql2, var2, function (err, res2) {
          if (err) { cb(err) }
          else { cb(null, res2) }
        })
      }
    },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) { cb(err) }
      else { cb(null, result) }
    })

}

run_queries(conn, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);       // UNDEFINED :(
  // GET OBJECT OF res1 AND res2
});
```

Comment: this worked and the structure is much simpler such that I can create a function for an arbitrary number of queries. thank you!!